# Schema migration in Objectify: AlsoLoad List<Entity> did not return the "whole" entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Objectify4+GAE 1.7.1

Before migration: the entity has a field:

```
@Load
List<ChildEntity> children=new ArrayList<ChildEntity>();
```

Now i want to delete this field and instead use:

```
 List<String> childrenNames=new ArrayList<String>();
```

According to Objectify doc, i use below method:

```
    void importPreviousChildren( @AlsoLoad( "children" ) List<ChildEntity> children )
    {
        for( ChildEntity c: children )
        {
            if( !childrenNames.contains( c.getName() ) )
                childrenNames.add( c.getName() );
        }
    }
```

But, the result is childrenNames field contain just "null". I guess the reason is, when loading children it does load the whole ChildEntity, So what's the correct way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are ChildEntity objects embedded entities or the Keys of other entities??

Comment: Yes, ChildEntity has 3 fields, one is the long id, one is the String name, and the other is @Parent Key<AppUser> owner. It seems did not load the name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally when objectify stores an Entitity *"in this case ChildEntity"* it doesn't store the entity itself, instead it stores the `key` "reference to the entity". Probably your method is never called because objectify handle a `List<Key>` and you have declared `List<ChildEntity>`.

you can try this code:

```
 void importPreviousChildren( @AlsoLoad( "children" ) List<Key> children )
    {
        for( Key key: children )
        {
            ChildEntity c = ofy().load().entity(DatastoreService.get(key))

            if( !childrenNames.contains( c.getName() ) )
                childrenNames.add( c.getName() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however i'm afraid your code above can pass compilation: DatastoreService.get(key) return com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity, and ChildEntity is obvious not this type, it simply marked as @Entity, do you think so?

Comment: Ok you are right, I have edited the answer. Just have to get the object from and objectify instance or whatever you want, the point is that you'll recieve a list of Keys instead ChildEntities.

Comment: I see the changes. But where can i get ofy()? I mean, this method's context is the Entity, when the entity is loading from datastore, i don't think we can get a ofy() at the time, except Objectify itself, right?

Comment: "void importPreviousChildren( @AlsoLoad( "children" )....)" is a method that objectify will call when it find the "children" property in the Entity and the arguments's type match. What you do inside this method is developer's matter, it's supposed you use it to update the new property however you can do whatever you want, even get the objectify instance "ObjectifyService.ofy()" and use it to get the Childentity.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again using your method, however it throw exception like below, How do you think the cause of this exception?java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException","X":"com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException

Comment: This answer is close.  You can make the parameter `List<Key<ChildEntity>> children` and then load all the keys `ofy().load().keys(children);`.  No need to muck with DatastoreService.  However, there is a simpler approach that I will make a separate answer for.  BTW ofy() works everywhere - as long as you have the ObjectifyFilter configured, it will always return "the right" context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void importPreviousChildren( @Load @AlsoLoad( "children" ) List<ChildEntity> children )
{
    for( ChildEntity c: children )
    {
        if( !childrenNames.contains( c.getName() ) )
            childrenNames.add( c.getName() );
    }
}
```

Note the extra @Load annotation.  You were loading "partial" entities - just the key fields.  You aren't supposed to be able to use concrete references without @Load anymore; the official release of Objectify4 will throw an exception if you try it.  In the past it was allowed but it turns out to be a bad idea for exactly this reason.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but i see the @Load annotation could be only added to "field": @Target({ElementType.FIELD}), and it will give me compile exception if i put it before method parameter, any ideas?

Comment: That's an oversight.  If you pull master, @Load can now be used on parameters.  There aren't any test cases for that right now, but it should work.  Alternatively, if you don't want to build from source, you can @AlsoLoad the values as `List<Key<ChildEntity>>` as I mention in my comment to the other answer.

Comment: I didn't try @Load, but using the above answer's solution, with a little changes, it works:  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity entity = datastore.get( tag );
                String tagName = ( String ) entity.getProperty( "name" );

Thanks!